# PHP - Randomized data displayed in text box when Submit is clicked

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

Hello I have a database and its data is this please see this image

[image: here is my image]

I need a solution to this problem, the solution is i need the data to be change and not repeating, so when i input a value that is written on the database the displayed value on the textbox will not REPEAT and Change everytime i input the same value.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <div class="row  col-md-4">
        <label>Amount</label>
        <input type="text" name="id" class="form-control validate"> 
        <br>
        <input type="submit" class="form-control btn-warning" name="search" value="Search Data"></input><br>
        //HERE IS WHERE I SUBMIT THE DATA RIGHT NOW IT IS NOT RANDOMIZED WHEN I SUBMIT AGAIN THE SAME VALUE APPEARS

<?php 
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
    $db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'qrproject');

    if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM scratch_cards WHERE amount='$id' ";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run)) {
?>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="code" value="<?php echo $row['code'] ?>" class="form-control validate" id="mapo">
            <input type="text" name="pin" value="<?php echo $row['pin'] ?>" class="form-control validate" id="mact">
            <input type="text" name="status" value="<?php echo $row['status'] ?>" class="validate form-control" id="soluong">
            <input type="date" name="card_expiration" value="<?php echo $row['card_expiration'] ?>" class="validate form-control" id="cardex">
            <input type="number" name="card_validity" value="<?php echo $row['card_validity'] ?>" class="validate form-control" id="cardval">
        </form>
<?php 
    }
}
?>   
</form>
```

Comment: I'm extremely curious as to why you're looking to do that?

Comment: Please clarify your problem.

Comment: Ahh, so you want to fetch a random matching record from DB, not insert random data. Is this correct?

Comment: I am not sure...what you asked for but you can use DISTINCT in your query so it will only give unique records no repeated...

Comment: 'SELECT * FROM scratch_cards WHERE amount = 500 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;'

Comment: You are also looping out multiple forms in your while loop.  That will cause some problems at some point for you.

Comment: Sorry not able to understand your issue. Please let us know your expected result

Comment: Warning: your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: Warning 2: **Never** get your web app to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes,
so on top of the SQL injection vulnerabilities
this just leaves your database an open book for hackers.
Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly.
Don't even use the root account as a shortcut during development or testing, because you need to test your account permissions as well - otherwise when you go live you might have unexpected errors relating to the user account setup.

Comment: @Joseph_J indeed it might, depending on the circumstances (multiple forms is not an issue _in itself_, but could become one depending on the desired use case for the page). Although, considering there's no way of submitting these forms, it's unclear why a form (or input fields) is even being created. Perhaps OP could clarify that separately. And what definitely _is_ a problem, is the fact that all the input fields have IDs, and these will be duplicated due to the looping, which creates invalid HTML.

Comment: @ADysan bro, take it easy my man, im just practicing php for my finals

Comment: @RiggsFolly can you explain your code sir please thanks

Comment: @Dipti hi sir, I just want to display my data in a textbox. so when i input `500` on my **FIRST** try,  it will display the data and on my second input of `500` it will display the OTHER id of 500. that is my input should be.   but what i've got now is when i input `500` on the second try the displayed value is STILL the SAME

Comment: @RiggsFolly I dont think your code will work, because `500` amount is not the only amount im inputting im also inputting `200` , `1000` etc.

Comment: Well of course you can always make the 500 bit a parameter

Comment: @JayminNoob , At Last, you understand my problem, can you please provide me  a code how can i use the `DISTINCT`on my query please? thank you sir

Comment: `'SELECT * FROM scratch_cards WHERE amount = ? ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;'`

Comment: And explanation of `RAND()` [can be found in any MYSQL Manual or tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/select-random-records-database-table.aspx)

Comment: @obitouchiha Please check answer

Comment: I am guessing that most if not all of us are not actually getting what you are actually trying to do here. Maybe it would benefit you to edit your question and try and make it very clear exactly what question you want us to answer

Comment: @RiggsFolly Edit done please see my clear problem thanks

Comment: Even with the edit, still not clear what exactly you want, or what your problem is. _“i need the data to be change and not repeating”_ - which field are you talking about, amount or code? Who changes it? Do you want to generate a new _random_ value, but one that was not used before - or what? _“the displayed value on the textbox will not REPEAT and Change everytime i input the same value”_ - which part of this _are_ you inputting manually, and what do you want to change based on that?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe as per your comment, you need unique records, so you can use `DISTINCT` in your query so by giving DISTINCT to any column, you won't get repeated records.

Here in your case:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, amount FROM scratch_cards WHERE amount='$id'
```

Maybe this can help you to get unique records

Comment: `Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in ` here is my error